# Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

Hi i am currently trying out michael hartl's tutorial but i kept getting failed tests. 
One of the tests failed is:

```
2) Authentication authorization in the Users controller visiting the edit page                                                         
     Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(user) }                                                                                
     NameError:                                                                                                                          
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x007fa22126f438
>                                                                                                                                        
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:111:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Attached is the code for authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            expect(page).to have_title('Edit user')
          end

          describe "when signing in again" do
            before do
              click_link "Sign out"
              visit signin_path
              fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
              fill_in "Password", with: user.password
              click_button "Sign in"
            end

            it "should render the default (profile) page" do
              expect(page).to have_title(user.name)
            end
          end
        end
      end

      describe "in the Relationships controller" do
        describe "submitting to the create action" do
          before { post relationships_path }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
          before { delete relationship_path(1) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end

      describe "in the Microposts controller" do

        describe "submitting to the create action" do
          before { post microposts_path }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
          before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
      end

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "visiting the following page" do
          before { visit following_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "visiting the followers page" do
          before { visit followers_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end
      end
    #end

     describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end

    describe "as non-admin user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      before { sign_in non_admin, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
        before { delete user_path(user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Please do not paste all your code, only the relevant parts

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire Pretty much the whole thing turned out to be relevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `end` on line 106, while the right `end` is commented out on line 135. The first `end` terminates the `describe` block where `user` is defined, which is why RSpec is saying that it doesn't know what it is.